# X shaped cursor in lxde over xrdp, until lxappearance is started

Tags: gtk, lxde, cursor, xrdp

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 server on which I usually log in over `xrdp`.

The `DefaultWindowManager` script contains the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
startlxde
```

Now, when I log in I just get the default black X as cursor. But as soon as I start `lxappearance` (just starting it, not doing anything) I get a proper cursor.

When I log in through `lightdm` I get a proper cursor from the beginning.

However, in both cases changes to the cursor are only applied, after I start a new session.

The selected cursor theme is stored in a couple of files

```
.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini:5:gtk-cursor-theme-name=Breeze_Snow
.config/lxsession/LXDE/desktop.conf:34:sGtk/CursorThemeName=Breeze_Snow
.gtkrc-2.0:8:gtk-cursor-theme-name="Breeze_Snow"
.icons/default/index.theme:5:Inherits=Breeze_Snow
```

Did I miss installing or running something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have at least a partial answer to my question. However I am still looking for a nicer and better solution!

---

As indicated by this [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cursor_themes#Change_X_shaped_default_cursor) entry, running `xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr` also gets rid of the X shaped cursor.

I ended up adding this to `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart`. So now it reads

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr
```

It is also required that all users either delete their `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart` or change it accordingly.

---

If logging in through LightDM it seems to be the default behavior that cursor changes are not immediately applied. Also here a `xsetroot -cursor_name left_ptr` executed from a terminal fixes that.